# rails4 authentication with has_secure_password not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting the following log fil output when I logon in the log file:

```
Started POST "/login" for x.x.x.x at 2015-09-15 17:40:56 -0400
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MO/Efr8/893XItcJdmNGsrq1iZ0
94AS/+GubuIRcpIhqZcWoRXyFnOK15TjoJOtfD9BUhDRKV2fpb1Gk1EqTSw==", "session"=>{"e
mail"=>"5@5.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"
."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_secure_password

   validates :password_digest, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

The new.html in app/view/sessions is as follows

**new.html.erb in app/view/sessions**

```
<% provide(:title, "Log in") %>
<h1>Log in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My application.html.erb file is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>RailsBlog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

          <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>  Welcome, <%= current_user.email %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

My session.controller file is as follows:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

My application.controller file is as follows

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

include SessionsHelper
=begin
  private
   def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
   end

   helper_method :current_usera
=end
    helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?

    def current_user
       @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
   end

  def logged_in?
      current_user != nil
   end
end
```

My SessionsHelper as as follows (from helper directory)

```
module SessionsHelper
#Logs in the given user
  def log_in(user)
      session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

#returns the current logged-in user (if
  def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

end
```

**routes.rb file:**

```
get 'signup' => 'users#new'
get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users   # , only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :authors
  resources :posts
  resources :sessions
 # get 'posts/index'

    root 'users#index'
```

I have bcrypt enabled in my Gem file and I ran bundle install after that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You also have a significant bug in how you validate the password length. Do **not** validate the length of the *digest* (which will always be longer than 6 characters, btw). Validate the length of the *password*.

Instead of:

```
validates :password_digest, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

Use:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The session fields from your form will be passed to your controller under `params[:session]`, so you want to use

`user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])`

rather than

`user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])`.